# How to do Until loop check using vbs?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am running the following vbs script,

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

for Process in Service.Instanceof ("Win32_Process")
If Process.Name = "notepad.exe" then
Wscript.echo "Notepad running"
Wscript.quit
End If
next
Wscript.echo "notepad not running"
```

it displays `Notepad running` if it runs
and displays `Notepad not running` if its not runs..

But, i need this program to loop until the notepad close.
Once notepad close it need to open a file `run.bat`

Note : only if notepad close it need to run `run.bat` if notepad not close it need to keep on checking until it close (in background)

Pls help me guys..So much of thanx ...in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When transferring code you should take care to do it right - there were some flaws.

This vbscript should do:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

Function IsAppRunning(AppName)
    for Each Process in Service.Instancesof("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(AppName) then
            IsAppRunning = True
            Exit function
        End If
    next
    IsAppRunning = False
End Function

AppName = "notepad.exe"

' initial test
If IsAppRunning(AppName) then
    Wscript.echo AppName & " running - waiting for it to exit"
else
    Wscript.echo AppName & " not running - exiting"
    Wscript.quit
End If

Do while IsAppRunning(AppName)
    Wscript.Sleep(1000) 'wait miliseconds
Loop

Wscript.echo AppName & " exited, do your task"

' Reaching here AppName had been running - but no more.
'
' open or run "run.bat"
```

Comment: Finally It works. I struggled whole day for this code. Thank u very very much from my heart... U are my life saver... U are my god. No words to thank u... You are really fantastic man.. You donno how happy i am now... Once again and again.. Thank you sooooooooooooooo much... 